# SQL - missing time in date range

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-range, gaps-and-islands

I have data in a table that shows if ignition `true` or `false`

```
|--------------------------------------|
|             date          | ignition |
|---------------------------|----------|
|2019-06-03 10:15:00.000000 | false    |
|---------------------------|----------|
|2019-06-03 10:30:00.000000 | false    |
|---------------------------|----------|
|2019-06-03 11:30:00.000000 | true     |
|---------------------------|----------|
|2019-06-03 11:45:00.000000 | false    |
|---------------------------|----------|
|2019-06-03 11:55:00.000000 | false    |
|---------------------------|----------|
```

I wrote SQL query that show ignition status in date period

```
SELECT min(date) as date_from, max(date) as date_to, ignition
FROM (SELECT date,
             ignition,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by ignition order by date) as seqnum_s
      FROM table_data
      WHERE date >= '2019-06-01T21:00:00.000Z' AND date <= '2019-06-09T20:59:59.999Z'
    ) as raw_data
GROUP BY (seqnum - seqnum_s), ignition
ORDER BY min(date);
```

Query result:

```
|---------------------------|----------------------------|----------|
|             date_from     | date_to                    | ignition |
|---------------------------|----------------------------|----------|
|2019-06-03 10:15:00.000000 | 2019-06-03 10:30:00.000000 | false    |
|---------------------------|----------------------------|----------|
|2019-06-03 11:30:00.000000 | 2019-06-03 11:30:00.000000 | true     |
|---------------------------|----------------------------|----------|
|2019-06-03 11:45:00.000000 | 2019-06-03 11:55:00.000000 | false    |
|---------------------------|----------------------------|----------|
```

But date from `10:30` to `11:30` and date from `11:30` to `11:45` missing in result. I should get this one:

```
|---------------------------|----------------------------|----------|
|             date_from     | date_to                    | ignition |
|---------------------------|----------------------------|----------|
|2019-06-03 10:15:00.000000 | 2019-06-03 11:30:00.000000 | false    |
|---------------------------|----------------------------|----------|
|2019-06-03 11:30:00.000000 | 2019-06-03 11:45:00.000000 | true     |
|---------------------------|----------------------------|----------|
|2019-06-03 11:45:00.000000 | 2019-06-03 11:55:00.000000 | false    |
|---------------------------|----------------------------|----------|
```

The problem is that during aggregation into one block (e.g. 5 following rows of false) he only looks at the last row of false to determine the end time of the block instead of the first following row (the first that is true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, just use window function `lead` to get the next row's value of `date_from`, then set this value into the current row's `date_to`, the SQL as below:

```
select 
    date_from,
    case when lead(date_from,1) over(order by date_from) is null then date_to else lead(date_from,1) over(order by date_from) end as date_to,
    ignition
from (
SELECT min(date) as date_from, max(date) as date_to, ignition
FROM (SELECT date,
             ignition,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by ignition order by date) as seqnum_s
      FROM table_data
      WHERE date >= '2019-06-01T21:00:00.000Z' AND date <= '2019-06-09T20:59:59.999Z'
    ) as raw_data
GROUP BY (seqnum - seqnum_s), ignition
ORDER BY min(date)
) tmp;
      date_from      |       date_to       | ignition 
---------------------+---------------------+----------
 2019-06-03 10:15:00 | 2019-06-03 11:30:00 | f
 2019-06-03 11:30:00 | 2019-06-03 11:45:00 | t
 2019-06-03 11:45:00 | 2019-06-03 11:55:00 | f
(3 rows)
```

Comment: And your usage of using `row_number` twice is ingenious, which has helped to solve a history problem of mine.Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to express this is:

```
SELECT min(date) as date_from,
       lead(min(date)) over (order by min(date)) as date_to,
       ignition
FROM (SELECT d.*,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by ignition order by date) as seqnum_s
      FROM table_data d
      WHERE date >= '2019-06-01T21:00:00.000Z' AND date < '2019-06-09T21:00:00Z'
     ) as raw_data
GROUP BY (seqnum - seqnum_s), ignition
ORDER BY min(date)
```